# T-SQL Error WITH Azure Synapse SQL Serverless when using FOR JSON in subquery

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

The query using `FOR JSON PATH` in a subquery to generate a JSON array as a column results in this error:

> The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode.

```
SELECT
    shift.id AS Id, 
    shift.shifttype AS ShiftType, 
    shift.resource AS ResourceId, 
    (SELECT shift2.id AS Id
     FROM [dbo].[shift] shift2
     WHERE shift2.resource = shift.resource 
     FOR JSON PATH) AS FutureShifts
FROM 
    [dbo].[shift] shift
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Shift')
```

Is anyone able to tell me the cause of the error?

Is this a limitation for Synapse SQL Serverless?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The error the query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode occurs when you use an object or function that cannot be used while you query data in Azure Storage or Azure Cosmos DB analytical storage.

**Reference:**
[Query references an object that isn't supported in distributed processing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#query-references-an-object-that-isnt-supported-in-distributed-processing-mode)

In your situation , an error in your SQL query because you are using the **FOR JSON PATH** in a subquery to create a **JSON array** as a column
This is not supported in distributed processing mode.

This is a limitation of Synapse SQL Serverless.
You can work around this by using Azure Databricks OR Synapse SPARK notebooks to generate the **JSON array** and then querying the data from Synapse SQL Serverless pool.

I have used bleow as an  example JSON file:

```
[
  {"name": "John", "age": 25, "gender": "Male"},
  {"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "gender": "Female"},
  {"name": "Bob", "age": 22, "gender": "Male"}
]
```

I have read the JSON file from the ADLS and using databricks and  generated the **JSON array** as a column using the `collect_list` function.

```
json_array_column = to_json(collect_list(to_json(struct("*")))).alias("json_array")
result = df.select(json_array_column)
result.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_array                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|["{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":25,\"gender\":\"Male\"}","{\"name\":\"Alice\",\"age\":30,\"gender\":\"Female\"}","{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":22,\"gender\":\"Male\"}"]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Next I have saved the results of the query to Delta format in ADLS.
Query the Delta folder from Synapse SQL Serverless to retrieve the data.

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://dilipstgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/folder02/output/',
        FORMAT = 'DELTA'
    ) AS [result]
```

[image]